# Access violation error when releasing SparseMat

Tags: c++, opencv, sparse-matrix

I'm working on 3D sparse matrices in OpenCV and I get this Access Violation Error when I try to call release method of cv::SparseMat (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#sparsemat-release).

Also some notes on OpenCV's memory management: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management

Here's the isolated version of my problem:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cv::SparseMat smat2;

    smat2 = Test();
    smat2.release(); //access violation error
}

cv::SparseMat Test()
{
    const int sizes[] = {480, 640, 3000};
    cv::SparseMat mat(3, sizes, CV_8SC1);
    return mat;

}
```

And the internal code where the error occurs is:

```
inline void SparseMat::release()
{
    if( hdr && CV_XADD(&hdr->refcount, -1) == 1 )
        delete hdr; // <--- HERE!
    hdr = 0;
}
```

It's been some time for me with memory management and C++. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It happens *after* `release()` was called, right, i.e. when `smat2` goes out of scope?

Comment: Yes it happens when I call `release()`, within the `inline void SparseMat::release()` function.

Comment: Does the same happen when you replace `smat2 = Test();` with `cv::SparseMat smat2 = Test();`?

Comment: Yes, same error. My current workaround: I define the test function as `void Test(cv::SparseMat& mat)` and no errors.

Comment: The code is working fine. You may be mixing `Debug` and `Release` libraries. Make sure you link the correct versions of opencv libs for each of the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had something to do with my misconfiguration of dynamic libraries of OpenCV. When I copied correct dlls (opencv_core245.dll under \Release, opencv_core245d.dll under \Debug and so on) problem solved.

It's still interesting though, I changed my %PATH% variable to contain `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin` folder, which contains both release and debug dll's, yet I had to manually copy dll files to corresponding project folders.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: "const int sizes[]". This means you are creating array on the stack (not on the heap) in function Test(). It is automatically de-allocated when you leave the function, so trying to release this memory later will lead to exception. Actually any attempt to release memory on stack is "problematic".

Comment: No that is not the problem. The `sizes` array has nothing to do with internal allocation of `cv::SparseMat`. It is just specifying the size of the dimensions of the matrix. The code is correct.

Comment: Eh, my bad. Somehow I thought that you are passing the 'sizes' as pointer to data, not definition of matrix dimentions. I tested your code and it runs OK. What OS you are using?

Comment: Well, the OP will be able to tell that because I didn't ask the question :p

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 64bit, Opencv 2.4.5, on VS2012 (but also installed VS2010 for msvcp100d.dll). Running on release x64 configuration (with correct libs).

Comment: I have the same system (Windows 7, OpenCV 2.4.5, VS2010) so the problem should not be here. And what will happen if you are not using release() function (i.e. its destructor is called at end of main)? What happening if you are putting at least one element to matrix before releasing it? And what for are you using release function?

Comment: I think it happens any time the `release()` is called. Whether I call it explicitly, or `cv::SparseMat` variable goes out of scope, or I clear a `vector<cv::SparseMat>`. I already said "correct libs" but now I'm not so sure...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to link to the right library `opencv_world320.lib` if you are building a release build. Or `opencv_world320d.lib` if you are building a debug build (this assumes version `3.2.0` of `OpenCV`).